# How to use angularJs filter on ng-model

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having json as below

```
  var content = [{
  "DocList": [
   {
  "Events": [
    {
      "CategoryName": "PressStatements",
      "DisplayName": "Press Statements",
      "ID": 9
    },
    {
      "CategoryName": "Reports",
      "DisplayName": "Reports",
      "ID": 10
    }
  ],
  "Heading": "News 2",
  "PageID": 23,
   "Date": "\/Date(1454537792000)\/"

},
{
  "Events": [
    {
      "CategoryName": "Research",
      "DisplayName": "Research",
      "ID": 6
    }
  ],
  "Heading": "Heading",
  "PageID": 20,
  "Date": "\/Date(1437417792000)\/"
}
]}
];


$scope.data=content;

 $scope.filterItems = function(g) {
//console.log('filterItems is run');
var ret = $filter('filter')(g.NewsList,"");
//g.filteredItemCount = ret.length
return ret
 };

 $scope.abms = [];


 //Options Inside Select tag
angular.forEach(news[0].NewsList, function(newsItems, index) {
  angular.forEach(newsItems.CategoryList, function(category, index){
    $scope.abms.push(category.DisplayName);
  });
});
```

i'm displaying Events in select option depending upon that i have to display the data, for selection i'm using select tag with ng-model

```
<select ng-model="selected"><option ng-repeat="item1 in abms" >{{item1}}</option></select>
   <div id="dataRow{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item1 in (filtered = filterItems(d)) | findobj:selected">

  //display data depending on option selection

  </div>
```

If i select any categoryName from Events[0] then it should display data from DocList[0] data and same to other for select option.

//filter - dont knw this the way to do it

```
myapp.filter('findobj', function() {
  return function(dataobj, selected) {
  return dataobj.filter(function(news) {
  //alert('got something');
    return (selected || []).some(function(s) {
    alert('got something');
    return news.CategoryList.CategoryName === s.CategoryList.CategoryName;
    });
   });
 };
});
```

How to achieve that?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: what is `findobj` filter? it custom filter? can you provide working sample on jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: @Grundy  im trying to implement  findobj filter

Comment: add this to your post also :-)

Comment: @Grundy its not working or may be wrong way to do..dont knw ;-)

Comment: can you provide working plunker?

Comment: @Grundy https://jsfiddle.net/1joo0j77/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82825/discussion-between-grundy-and-flash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need fix your `findobj` filter something like this

```
myapp.filter('findobj', function () {
    return function (dataobj, selected) {
        if (!selected) return dataobj;//if nothing selected - return initial array
        return dataobj.filter(function (news) {
            //select only news where in category list places selected category
            return news.CategoryList.some(function (category) {
                //check display category name
                return category.DisplayName === selected;
            });
        });
    };
});
```

working sample on **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1joo0j77/4/)**